# Unable to Find Element on Qualtrics using Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, qualtrics

I've been using Python and Selenium to try to automate an export process in Qualtrics. I have the web driver navigate to the login page, input my login credentials, and then navigate to the Data and Analytics page of the relevant survey. However, once I navigate to the Data and Analysis page, I'm having trouble selecting the element for the dropdown icon under the action header, which I need to click in order to export the responses.

I've tried to use this code (omitting the part where I login):

```
from selenium import webdriver
survey_url= {The Survey Url}
browser= webdriver.Chrome() 
browser.get(survey_url)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='itemContext']").click()
```

However, I keep getting this error: **NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='itemContext']"}**

I've tried using both the absolute **(/html/body/div[6])** and the relative **(//*[@id="itemContext"])** xpath given to me by inspect element, but neither worked.

This is the **HTML** that I see for the element:

```
<div id="itemContext" ng-click="removeSelf()" qmenu items="recordActions" on-select="selectRecordAction()(value,rowId, recordIndex)" class="response-context ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" style="left:1315px;top:357px">
<span ng-transclude></span></div>
```

Here is the HTML for the webpage:

```
<html ng-app="responses-client">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Data | Qualtrics Experience Management</title>
        <script>
            (function (window) {
                'use strict';

                /*
                 * This function is used to attempt to get the initial definition before
                 * angular is loaded. If this fails for some reason the definition will
                 * still be loaded, but not via this function. See fast-definition-service.
                */

                function rejectError(data, status, statusText) {
                    data = data || {};

                    window.fastDefinitionState = 'ERROR';
                    window.fastDefinitionError = {
                        status: status || 500,
                        statusText: statusText || 'Internal Server Error',
                        data: data,
                        config: {
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: url
                        }
                    };
                }

                function handleResponse() {
                    var status = request.status;
                    var data;
                    try {
                        data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    } catch (e) {
                        data = request.responseText;
                    }

                    function handleSuccess() {
                        window.returnedDefinition = { data };
                        window.fastDefinitionState = 'SUCCESS';
                    }

                    if (status >= 200 && status < 400) {
                        return handleSuccess();
                    } else {
                        return rejectError(data, status, request.statusText);
                    }
                }

                function attemptRequest() {
                    request.open('GET', url, true);
                    request.onload = handleResponse; // Recieved response from server
                    request.onerror = rejectError; // Connection to server error
                    request.send();

                    window.fastDefinitionState = 'PENDING';
                }

                var surveyIdRegex = /surveys\/(SV_[a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/;
                var canonicalId = (surveyIdRegex.exec(window.location.hash) || [])[1];

                var fieldsetIdRegex = /fieldsets\/([\w-]+)/;
                var fieldsetId = (fieldsetIdRegex.exec(window.location.hash) || [])[1];

                var conjointIdRegex = /surveys\/SV_[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}\?conjointProjectId=(.+)/;
                var conjointId = (conjointIdRegex.exec(window.location.hash) || [])[1];

                var idpProjectRegex = /fieldsets\/[\w-]+\?(?:projectId|idpProjectId)=(IDP_.+|PROJ_.+)/;
                var idpProjectId = (idpProjectRegex.exec(window.location.hash) || [])[1];

                var resourceIdRegex = /surveys\/SV_[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}\?resourceId=(.+)/;
                var resourceId = (resourceIdRegex.exec(window.location.hash) || [])[1];

                var projectIdRegex = /surveys\/SV_[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}\?projectId=(.+)/;
                var projectId = (projectIdRegex.exec(window.location.hash) || [])[1];

                var url;

                if (canonicalId) {
                    url = '/responses/surveys/' + canonicalId;
                } else if (fieldsetId) {
                    url = '/responses/fieldsets/' + fieldsetId;
                } else {
                    return rejectError(new Error('Missing surveyId for fast definition'));
                }

                if (conjointId) {
                    url += '?optProjectId=' + conjointId;
                } else if (idpProjectId) {
                    url += '?idpProjectId=' + idpProjectId;
                } else if (resourceId) {
                    url += '?resourceId=' + resourceId;
                } else if (projectId) {
                    url += '?projectId=' + projectId;
                }

                window.fastDefinitionUrl = url;
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                return attemptRequest();
            })(window);
        </script>
        <link rel="icon" href="/brand-management/favicon">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/brand-management/apple-touch-icon">
        <link href="/responses/static/vendor/vendor.min.a113b2563.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="/responses/static/css/responsesclient.min.a49de54f5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body ng-click="checkMenu()" ng-controller="MainController" keep-alive style="margin:0px;">
        <div class="dp-container">
            <div ng-view></div>
            <div q-footer user-id="userId" language="userLanguage"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="/responses/static/vendor/vendor.min.a4f381856.js"></script>
    <script src="/responses/static/js/responsesclient.min.ad8d40058.js"></script>
    <script src="/wrapper/static/client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/project-workflow/static/bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://static-assets.qualtrics.com/static/expert-review-ui/prod/response-iq.js"></script>
    <script>

        window.Qualtrics = {"User":{"brandId":"mindshare";

        function hackAFixForProjectFramework() {
            var surveyIdRegex = /surveys\/(SV_[a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/;
            var fieldsetIdRegex = /fieldsets\/([\w-]+)/;

            var canonicalId = (surveyIdRegex.exec(window.location.hash) || [])[1];
            var fieldsetId = (fieldsetIdRegex.exec(window.location.hash) || [])[1];

            window.Qualtrics.surveyId = canonicalId || fieldsetId;
        }

        // Hack a fix for updating to jquery 3.5 breaking project framework as they assumed it was ready sooner with jquery 3.5. Couldn't discover why, but it's somewhere in their code base.
        hackAFixForProjectFramework();

        var user = _.get(window, 'Qualtrics.User', {}),
            requiredUserKeys = [
                'userId',
                'brandId',
                'brandName',
                'brandType',
                'language',
                'email',
                'userName',
                'firstName',
                'lastName',
                'accountType',
                'accountCreationDate'
            ];

        angular.module('responses-client').config([
            'rsw.userServiceProvider',
            function(userServiceProvider) {
                try {
                    userServiceProvider.setUser(_.pick(user, requiredUserKeys));
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }
        ]);
    </script>
</html>
```

I suspect the problem may be that the website is using a lot of javascript to dynamically change the responses. Above the HTML element I showed above, there are a bunch of "<'script type...'>" and src programs that I don't really understand, though I can guess from the names that they are handling the display of responses. Thinking it might be a loading problem, I've also tried making the program wait before searching for the element, but that didn't work either.

Cheers!

Comment: It might be easier to make Qualtrics API calls from Python to export the data you need.

Comment: If you make a html page yourself with that div can Selenium find it with that specific query? And how did you try to make that asynchronous?

Comment: We have absolutely nothing to do with pictures. Please provide us with the link to that page, if possible some test account credentials or at least the HTML code of entire page there.

Comment: I added the HTML of the entire webpage. Sorry for including the picture. I already tried to use the Qualtrics API. Sadly, it can only export all responses from Qualtrics into CSV. I am trying to export each specific response into a pdf. This was my way of trying to code a workaround.